# How to create a table with related images

Tags: mysql

I have a table with thousands of images, like so

```
image (image_id, title, caption, filename, inserted_date)
```

I want to be able to display related images to the user. So, for example, `image_id` `59` has 3 related `image_id` `(61, 589, 56)`. `image_id` `61`, by default, has 2 related `image_id` `(589, 56)`. If I add an `image_id` to `61` (let's say 25), then `image_id 59` now has 4 related images (`61`, `589`, `56` ad `25`).

I have no idea how to do the table for related images. Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your relationship is a tree like structure, then all you need to do is add in a new column - related_image_id.

Then you populate each parent related id. You then will need to write a recursive query to get all related images for a specific image.

Another option is to create a new table - related_images which has two columns, parent_image_id and related_image_id. You can use this if your data is not a tree like structure.